# Use a service account to read/update calendars of O365 users

Tags: c#, authentication, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to use a Service Account to read and update caldendars of O365 Users. All the users I want access to have shared their calendar with my account.

I have an app, that uses AAD v2.0 MSAL for auth. The problem is I want to use my credentials to update/read the calendars of these users, but I don't want to sign in with this account, I want the credentials to be stored and used when calling my API endpoint.

An example of this using Exchange webservices to send an email from a stored user:

```
public Office365MailSender()
        {
            _credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:0365MailAddress"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:0365MailPassword"]);
        }

        public void Send(EmailDto email)
        {
            var service = new ExchangeService
            {
                Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(_credentials)
            };

            var message = new EmailMessage(service);

            message.ToRecipients.Add(email.To);
            message.Subject = email.Subject;
            message.Body = email.Body;
            message.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;

            message.SendAndSaveCopy();
        }
```

Now I want to do the same for read/update users calendar, using MSAL.
Can this be done? If not, is there some other way of doing it, like using a certificate?

In ADAL for example we have these:

```
public AuthenticationResult AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential);
public Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential);
```

Comment: I don't know about doing it with the graph API. It is possible with Exchange Web Services and X.509 certs. You need to add EWS impersonation permission for the application and sign on using a certificate, before Office 365 EWS will let you impersonate users to read/write their calendars.

You still acquire a token for your app with ADAL, but use a ClientAssertionCertificate to identify the application. Then add the returned token to the subsequent EWS calls.

Comment: Thanks, but wondering if its possible without ADAL, i.e with MSAL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft authentication library (MSAL) does't support the Resource Owner Password Credential flow at present. You can check this by [UserCredential](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/MSAL.PCL/UserCredential.cs) 
class which doesn't provider the password property.

And based on the test, the app which register for Azure AD V2.0 endpoint also doesn't support this flow. We will get the exception like below if using the flow to acquire the access token:

[image]

And if you want the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint to support this flow you can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback). And if you have any idea about the Microsoft authentication library, you can discuss from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet).